# RequireJS & IE11 Compatibility Mode: RequireJS executes module even though required files are missing

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, requirejs

I am running a very simple script to explore using RequireJS in our SharePoint web pages.  The following works as it should in Chrome & IE 11 Edge Mode, but not in IE 11 in 10 Compatibility Mode.

Here's the code:

```js
require.config({
    baseUrl: '',
    paths: {
        jquery: 'jquery-2.7.2.min'  
    }
});

require(
    ['jquery'], 
    function($) {
        var jqobj = null;
        try {
            jqobj = $('html');
            console.warn('jquery loaded', {'some prop': 'some val', 'jqobj':jqobj});            
        }
        catch(ex) {
            console.warn('jquery not properly loaded', {"ex": ex});
        }
    }
);
```

In Chrome or IE 11 Edge Mode, RequireJS runs properly.  The code inside the function doesn't execute and the console reports this error:

"require.js:168 Uncaught Error: Script error for "jquery"
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror"

In IE 11 in 10 Compatibility Mode, RequireJS doesn't work the same. The console reports no error message and instead continues into the function which throws an error because jquery (aka $) is undefined.

Why does IE behave like this? Are there some additional steps to ensure code won't run if required modules aren't found?